# Stop idle ec2 instances

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2, ssh, cron

I'm currently building a remote dev setup on EC2 machines with Ubuntu. My problem: I often forget to stop the machines, which results in running overnight and costing me money. So I'm searching for an idle detection mechanism, that automatically shuts down the machines after 30 Minutes of inactivity.

I first tried CloudWatch alarms, but relying on CPU, network, disk... turned out to be useless: Processes on the server are causing CPU load and the file sync from my local machine to the dev server causes bytes over the network (even if it does not actually sync files, I guess mutagen is talking to the server to keep everything in sync).

My definition of "idle" would be: For 30 minutes there was no active SSH connection OR an active SSH connection with no commands sent. Plus a check inside some log files if there were any new requests, e.g. to a Rails server (maybe a check "data sent over a specific port" would also work).

So, my questions would be:

- Is there any way CloudWatch could handle this, that I'm unaware of?
- Is there any piece of software that does remotely what I'm trying to achieve?
- I found how to check for open SSH connections, but not for active SSH connections without commands for a period of time. Any idea on how to get that?

Comment: I'd imagine that researching options that actually run on the Ubuntu instance and shut it down from within might be better, given the level of customization you want.

Comment: Set an inactivity timeout on your ssh sessions and automatically disconnect them.

Comment: I am looking for something similar. An idle CPU (<5%) alarm does not help because the server runs a process that starts off another remote process and waits for responses which could be few and far between. During such periods I do not want the server to be considered idle.

Check this file:
main/solution/post-deployment/config/environment-files/offline-packages/sagemaker/autostop.py
in github.com/awslabs/service-workbench-on-aws

Comment: does this help? https://medium.com/geekculture/automatically-turn-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-31fedd363cad

Comment: thanks for the hint, but I solved it by writing a dedicated linux daemon for it that checks for activity (synced files, logged in SSH sessions...)

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting to :

1. [Set timeout](https://www.tecmint.com/increase-ssh-connection-timeout/) on on `ssh` sessions. So that idle sessions are removed.
2. Create a service to monitor `ssh` count. So that it shuts down the system after all `ssh` connection dropped and few mins.

Comment: The problem here is, when you have long running commands the sshd daemon drops the connection without any user input. For example, I trigger a docker build and watch the progress and the output is sent via SSH to the client, but the server still drops the connection after the seconds defined in `ClientAliveInterval`. Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: Long pending process that are non interactive, should run in `nohup` command. Therefore their session will terminate with them.